# How do I make a button navigate to different screens depending on if the user is on iOS or android?

Tags: react-native

I would to know how to set up a button in React Native so it can navigate to a different screen if the user is on iOS vs android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can use the logic below.

```
 onClick={() => Platform.OS === 'ios' ? this.props.navigation.navigate('screenIOS') : this.props.navigation.navigate('screenAndroid')}
```